# How to call java script functions in objective C in cocos2d JS

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

How to call java script functions in objective C in cocos2d JS.

I found JS to Objective C [here](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/reflection/en).

Now i am trying JS to objective C calling.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/html5/v3/reflection-oc/en.md) is the official document.

if you want to call more than static method, you may write js-binding codes,there are many samples in cocos2dx-js source code.